# Implementing a clone function

Tags: java, exception, clone

I have a class named Garage :

```
class Garage extends Vehicle implements Cloneable
{
    Vehicle[] v= new Vehicle [10];

    public Garage ()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            this.v[i]=new Vehicle ();
    }

    public Garage clone () throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        try 
        {
            return (Garage) super.clone ();
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
            return null;    
        }
    }

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Garage g1,g2;
    g1=new Garage ();

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        g1.v[i].setVehicleAttr (i,i,i,Integer.toString(i));

    g2=new Garage ();
    g2 = g1.clone ();
}
};
```

When I compile it.. It give The Following Error...
Even Though i have handled the exception it says exception must be caught...Why is this happening....?

`Garage.java:32: error: unreported exception CloneNotSupportedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        g2 = g1.clone ();`

Comment: clone should be in try catch block.

Comment: I don't think garage should extend vehicle necessarily though, it doesn't make sense to extend vehicle and have an array of vehicles in this case.

Comment: @IanSellar, you mean you don't want to fill your garage with other garages?  ;-)

Comment: Consider using a copy constructor as opposed to "clone". "clone" can be tricky to override, and you can achieve the same functionality with a copy constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no you haven't: `g2 = g1.clone ();` is not in a try/catch block for the exception that the `clone()` method you're written is supposed to throw.

Even if you catch the throw inside the method (*which you should **not** do*), your signature still tells java that the method *will* throw under unknown conditions, and thus code that calls it *must* use a try/catch, or the method inside which the call is made *must* itself have a `throw CloneNotSupportedException`.

Either try/catch inside the method and don't declare a throw, or do declare a throw and then let the calling code handle the try/catch.

Comment: "Even if you catch the throw inside the method (which you should not do) ..." I consider this statement as wrong. Catching the CNSE _inside_ the `clone` method is correct if you are sure that it never can happen. The correct approach would be to throw an error in this case. Additionally the method should _not_ declare the CNSE in its signature. And that would lead to the OP's desired behavior.

Comment: No, catching inside the method is nonsense if the function signature declares that it will throw. Either try/catch without a throw declaration because you've ensured it cannot throw, or declare the throw and then don't interfere because calling code must already deal with it.